# Can I soak liver overnight in milk?

Tags: milk, soaking, liver, timing

Can I soak liver in milk overnight? And if yes, does it matter if I soak it for 2 hours or overnight, or will there be no difference?

Comment: In my personal humble opinion there's no discernable difference between overnight, 2h and no soak.

Answer (score -1):

On one hand there is theory that keeping the liver in milk overnight (in the fridge) let it get more tender and flush bitterness even better than for two hours.
But if it was the "success rate", the overnight soak would be the advised time for soaking.

The main times for soaking I've seen are "kissed" when you cut the liver in small pieces and soak for 30 minutes. The second is whole liver for two-three hours.
When leaving in milk for overnight I usually see adnotation that it help cook it quicker as liver is "fluffier" thus helping the heat go through it.

Comment: Do “fluffy” things heat up more efficiently?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not ready to cook my beef liver til the next day so I am soaking mine in milk overnight covered in the fridge. Just easierm and to get it out of the package and I don't think it would hurt any being in fridge overnight.

Comment: But is there a difference? soaked / not soaked, 2h, overnight? I think covering these points would make a better answer than just an anecdote. Check [answer] for more info